# Format range with fmt without enclosing [] brackets

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

I want to print a range of values with `,` separator but without `[]` using fmt library.

If I try to print out some range like this

```
std::vector v {8,4,7,2};
std::cout  << fmt::format("{}",v) <<"\n";
```

the output is

> [8, 4, 7, 2]

But I actually want the output to be

> 8, 4, 7, 2

How can I do this?

---

One approach I've found is to do the following

```
std::cout  << fmt::format("{}",fmt::join(v,", ")) <<"\n";
```

which does work. However, it's verbose, and it makes 2 calls to fmt,
which I would like to avoid. Is this possible?

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q9qWo6cq4)

Also, due to performance and readability reasons I am not interested in removing `[]` from the string produced by fmt.

Comment: there are no `[]` in the output https://godbolt.org/z/GcK53TzsG

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I know, but it requires 2to calls to fmt, I would like something shorter

Comment: Well, [`fmt::print("|{}|",fmt::join(v,","));`](https://godbolt.org/z/v77xGd1Ye) *is* less verbose. unless you want to hack `fmt.ranges.h`: https://godbolt.org/z/6Yd134o9c

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: So is your question about `[]` or is it about making one call instead of two?

Comment: @NicolBolas "I figured out I can use this, but I would like something less verbose."

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Figured *what* out? What `[]` are you talking about? Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah, the question was unclear. I've edited it a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: Side-note: On the performance front, removing the `[]` isn't that expensive; wrap the result of `fmt::format` in a `string_view`, then use either `.remove_prefix(1)` and `.remove_suffix(1)` or just `.substr(1, sv.size() - 2)` to shrink the view (without performing any data copies; the `_suffix` stuff even operates in place, though it can't be chained).

Comment: I've only skimmed the libfmt code but I think `fmt::join` just returns a range view, it doesn't concatenate or copy the input or anything when called, so there's not much cost there. I assume `fmt::format()` or `fmt::print()` will just use that range view rather than doing the default behavior (built in range_formatter with brackets and commas) with user supplied ranges, and therefore performance would be similar?   It would be nice to have some option just disable that behavior though (no added brackets or commas, just format and write each item from the range with no separators.)

Answer (score 5):

The shorter code is to use `fmt` to do the printing directly, rather than just using it to format, then passing the result to normal `cout` the `iostream` way:

```
fmt::print("{}\n", fmt::join(v, ", ")); // Optionally, I believe you can use the literals to make the format string compile-type checked, "{}\n"_format
```

The format string incorporates the newline as well, and `print` does both the formatting and printing, so it's markedly shorter/less complex than:

```
std::cout << fmt::format("{}", fmt::join(v, ", ")) << "\n";
```